# Slow download (client side) in Angular 7, how to track down the reason?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest

The download of a large REST service result in Angular 7 (2MB of json) takes longer than a minute. Chrome debugger shows download in 8k pieces with a delay of 1000ms (sometimes more).

I tried with Chrome and Firefox, there is no difference.
If I do the same via swagger-UI, the download takes only about a second. So it seems not a server side problem.
A former version (half year ago, older Angular version) of the software does not have this problem.

The code that creates the observable is essentially this:

```
    return this.http[method](...params, requestOptions)
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                this.updateToken(response.headers);
                if (response.body && !isNotOmitHeaders) {
                    return response.body;
                } else {
                    return response;
                }
            }),
            catchError(this.processError)
        );
```

and the only change from the last version in the usage of pipe.

What could cause such a delay? Is there any option to limit data bandwidth?
Has anything changed with Angular 6 or 7 that could cause this? Are there any suggestions how to further track down this problem?

Comment: How long does the request take, when you remove the _pipe(map())_ part?

Comment: how long does it take to parse a json of 2MB?

Comment: Without pipe(map()) it takes the same time.

Comment: Look into the network tab of the debug tools. How long does the HTTP response take to return?

Comment: The service side needs about 30-40s to compute the result, the download takes 1.4min (ca. 8kB/s). In the performance tab I see a receive data of 8kB every 1000ms.

Comment: That's weird. Why is the response split into small portions? That doesn't make sense

Comment: Use this options in your request `{reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'}` and you will receive events about downloading, it will help you in debugging

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. It is on the server side (what I thought I had excluded). There was a slightly changed parameter in the request that seems to result in additional DB requests while building json result stream. When I fix the parameters in the swagger UI, it takes also that long.

Thanks for the help!